# Why am I getting a 500 error with these RewriteRules

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, 500-error

I am setting up a site on a shared hosting plan so I am stuck using Apache and a .htaccess file. I have 2 RewriteRules defined. Both rules work perfectly on a local machine running Apache.

The first rule is to rewrite requests for /css/FILE.css to /www/css/FILE.css The second rewrites everything else to /www/index.php

The first rule regarding CSS/JS files is the one causing 500 errors but I can't figure out why. I have tried every different incarnation of these rules and always get a 500.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(css|js) www/$1.$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you get an error accessing those resources directly, at the post-rewritten URLs?

Comment: Yes but I just attributed it to the fact that it is getting caught in the same RewriteRule.

Comment: I was writing that comment above and thought maybe it is getting caught in an infinite loop? But I have add NS flag and it didn't help either.

Comment: try changing the first rule to catch terminations only _(css|js)$_

Comment: Changed to `RewriteRule (css|js)$ www%{REQUEST_URI} [L]` and still get 500. Also, if i rewrite to somewhere else other than /www it will work.

Comment: It was apparently just getting caught an infinite loop. I changed to `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(?!www).*\.(css|js)$ www%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!www)(.*)$ www/index.php [L]` and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(css|js) www/$1.$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/index.php [L]
```

Try that else you end up with a loop since the Rule would still apply after being rewritten so it would rewrite again and again...